# dwsscript Invalid Operands

Tags: delphi, dwscript

I'm getting a compilation error "Invalid Operands" when compiling my dws script with RTTIVariable types. Is it possible for the following to work?

Declare variable which is a form.

```
gVar := ScriptUnit.Variables.Add;
gVar.Name := 'MDIForm';
gVar.DataType := SYS_RTTIVARIANT;
gVar.OnReadVar := onGetMDI;

procedure TGuff.onGetMDI(info: TProgramInfo; var value: Variant);
begin
  value := TdwsRTTIVariant.FromObject(FMDIForm);
end;
```

The script does not compile on this line. Seems it wants a string only.

```
if (length(MDIForm.edit1.Text) = 0) then
```

All help appreciated

Comment: Maybe explicit the cast with: "if (length(String(MDIForm.edit1.Text)) = 0) then"

Comment: Yes if I go varToStr it does work. However I have alot (200+) of scripts we are converting over to DWS. Moreover I don't want to have to do this going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should now be supported in the trunk version, the type-check was a bit too strict and rejected RTTI (and OLE) variants.

Comment: Thanks Eric, have downloaded latest gear and it works. Keep up the great work with DWS very happy with it. It is awesome.